# Chrome: "continue where I left off" mode and Symfony2

Tags: php, security, google-chrome, symfony, fosuserbundle

Using Symfony2 and FOSUserBundle, I am not getting the expected behavior on the following implementation.

To begin, know that `Continue where I left off` option in Chrome restores completely the user session independently of having checked some "Remember me" or something like that. Therefor,it saves a cookie with all the information of the session.

What I am trying to do is to avoid the creation of a session from the cookie stored through that `Continue where I left off` option on Chrome.

Or, if I cannot avoid the creation of the session, at least try to know that the session comes from that completely transparent way.

I have found this in Symfony2 documentation (specifically [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/remember_me.html)):

> In some cases, however, you may want to force the user to actually re-authenticate before accessing certain resources. For example, you might allow "remember me" users to see basic account information, but then require them to actually re-authenticate before modifying that information.
>   The security component provides an easy way to do this. In addition to roles explicitly assigned to them, users are automatically given one of the following roles depending on how they are authenticated:
>   IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY - automatically assigned to a user who is in a firewall protected part of the site but who has not actually logged in. This is only possible if anonymous access has been allowed.
>   IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED - automatically assigned to a user who was authenticated via a remember me cookie.
>   IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY - automatically assigned to a user that has provided their login details during the current session.

So, if I don't get it wrong, a user that transparently logs in as a result of the `Copntinue where I left off` option, should have the IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED.

Well, the reality is that it is not thus. The reality is that the granting is IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY.

Has anyone passed through this?

Any idea on all this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sessions are handled server side. Depending on your server's configuration for sessions lifetime, you can close your browser and re-open it without losing the session. This has nothing to do with the `Continue where I left off` option of Google Chrome.

The granting is `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` because the session is still active on the server and not because of the Google Chrome option.

Simple example use case. Let's say we set a 5 minutes session lifetime.

**Without** the remember me option :

1. I log in : a session is created on the server.
2. I close the browser.
3. I come back 10 minutes later : session has expired therefore I have to provide my credentials.

**With** the remember option :

1. I log in : a session is created on the server **AND** a cookie is created on my browser saying *hey I'm connected*.
2. I close the browser.
3. I come back 10 minutes later : session has expired **BUT** as the result of the cookie saying *hey I'm connected*, a new session will be automatically created. Therefore I will not have to provide my credentials again.

In both case if you come back within the first 5 minutes you will be automatically logged in because the server still handle a session for your browser.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your response. But I still don't see it. I accept the fact that the Chrome option and the server side session configuration are separated features. But one of these two: 1. I am missing something in server session configuration (please, tell me how to change the session lifetime. 2. The Chrome option is so "magical" that it DOES save somehow the session and really restores it in a so pioneer way not known so far. I repeat the behavior: the user creates a session in chrome and just close the browser. If he enters in chrome after two months, the session remains.

Comment: And the worst part, I don't know where to intercept the creation of it (for example, to avoid the creation and redirect to login page)

Comment: One more data: $_COOKIE values the same at the moment of creating the session and two months ago. So the same session with the same ID and everything is recovered somehow.

Comment: Thanks again, I wait for your comments :)